# Ionic 2: How to use custom build Cordova Plugin

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm already created cordova plugin and already used in Ionic 1, its worked. Then I tried to use it in Ionic 2 but I don't really know how to call that plugin. I follow the step from [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/525) to create my own plugin. And this is what i did:

**plugin.xml**

```
<name>myPlugin</name>
<js-module src="www/myPlugin.js" name="myPlugin">
   <clobbers target="myPlugin" />
</js-module>
```

**myPlugin.js**

```
module.exports = {
  myFunction: function (success, failure) {         
    cordova.exec(success, failure, "myPlugin", "myFunction", []);
  }
};
```

**hello-ionic.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  constructor() {

  }

  click() {

    if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {
       cordova.plugins.myPlugin.myFunction();
    }
  } 
}
```

But unfortunately it return me an error **`"Undefined myFunction"`** in `hello-ionic.ts`.

Comment: havent created custom plugin.. but you should encapsulate plugin code in `Platform.ready()`

Comment: @suraj I'm already added the `Platform.ready()` but it still return me the same error `Type error: Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined`.

Comment: Have you tried using declare var myPlugin: any; and myPlugin.myFunction() instead of  cordova.plugins.myPlugin.myFunction();

Comment: @AishApp Yes, I'm already tried before, it return me same error. Btw thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did.

**hello-ionic.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var myPlugin: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  constructor() {

  }

  click() {
    myPlugin.myFuntion(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },

      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  } 
}
```

`declare var myPlugin: any;` , `myPlugin` name I get from `<clobbers target="myPlugin" />`.

**Note: Need to run the project in device only.**

Answer (score 2):

Following tutorial is a good resource to learn how to create custom cordova plugin :

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/

I have followed this tutorial to create multiple custom plugins and those are working fine in Ionic2.

One more thing to point out that the tutorial has not mentioned that:

You have to **add** your custom plugin in your ionic 2 project using following command:

> ionic plugin add "folder path of your custom plugin"

Updated:

In your plugin.xml file, you have set "myPlugin" as `target` in `clobbers` tag.

So you should call your function as followed

```
window.myPlugin.myFunction();
```

Tip: Whenever you use custom plugin created by you(or someone else), inspect the application using Chrome Developer tools. In console tab of developer tools, you can inspect the `window` and other available objects and can find out correct way to call plugin's methods.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already follow that tutorial to create the plugin. I made exactly like tutorial did, but it return me with same error `Type error: Cannot read property 'getNextAppointment' of undefined`.

Comment: Hi @sitiaishahismail, There may be issue in how you are calling your function. Check my updated answer.